# Can handle AccessViolationException ONLY on emulator and not on device

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having trouble with an AccessViolationException that gets thrown by a control I'm using (a RichEditBox).
I can't find a way to prevent the exception from being thrown since I don't exactly know why it gets thrown, so I put the code that generates the exception inside a try catch block.

The point is that if I try to run the app inside the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator, Visual Studio stops at the exception, and if I press continue the app keeps running fine. If I try to run it on my device, the debugger simply closes and the app crashes.

I don't know what am I missing here, why doesn't the try catch work outside of the emulator? :/

Thanks!

EDIT:
This happens when I try to call the SetText method on the Document property of my RichEditBox.
Something like this:

```
this.richEditBox.Document.Selection.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, "some random text...");
```

Or

```
this.richEditBox.Document.Selection.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, "some other text");
```

It happens both with FormatRtf and None, and I just can't find the reason why sometimes I get that exception.

Comment: If I run all that code you provided us to find your error, then... Well.. You know?

Comment: I added the specific line of code, I didn't write that before since I'm not sure it depends on it and I was just looking for a proper way to catch those kind of exception and to understand why I can only catch them inside the emulator. Anyways, I hope that helps, thanks! :)

Comment: An AVE is the nastiest possible thing that can happen to code.  Triggered by a hard fault in the processor, it cannot continue running the program.  There is no reasonable way to explain why it stays running in the emulator, it certainly is supposed to terminate the program.  But as long as you have no idea what the underlying reason might be then anything is possible.  You need help from Microsoft Support if you can't document this problem properly.

Comment: Ok, so should I post a thread in the msdn forum or is there another way to get support from MS? Thanks!

Comment: You don't happen to be updating the UI from a different thread, do you?

Comment: Nope, I'm changing the text of the selection inside the richeditbox from a synchronous method in the UI thread. And I only get that exception randomly, I don't understand *why* sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't :(
I call the method from the same event from the same button, and the method *always* adds the exact same string to the selection.
I really don't get why sometimes it crashes and other works fine.
Also: i get the same exception even if I try to assign a string to the Text property of the selection. This crashes randomly as well.